# How many Sahih(Authentic) Hadith are there?

Tags: uloom-al-hadith

From the size of the major Hadith collections, I'd estimate that there are only around 80 thousand at most, including overlapping Hadith. Some links (quite unreliable) seem to put the number closer to 10 thousand unique Sahih(Authentic) Hadith.

Is there a study that identifies exactly how many are out there? If not, what are the major Sahih(Authentic) Hadith collections?

To be precise, I'd like to know from a Sunni perspective. But answers from other sects would be interesting.

Comment: Different people view different Hadith as Sahih. You need to be a bit specific to get a better estimate.

Comment: @mezhang: Agreed, but that's part of the answer. I'm guessing that someone has done a study summarizing all this, also including the school/sect that they take the perspective from. Edited the question to say that I'm accepting an answer from a Sunni perspective, but other answers are welcome.

Comment: A possible answer of your inquiry appears as a by-product in my answer on https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25875/is-musnad-ahmed-a-book-of-sahih-ahaadith/35443#35443

Answer (score 2):

As I learnt in my childhood about `Sahih Al-Bukhari` and `Sahih Al-Muslim`,

Imam Bukhari himself counted approx. 4000 hadith sahih without repetition (same verse or meaning from different person or chain)

Imam Muslim himself counted approx. 2000 hadith sahih without repetition (same verse or meaning from different person or chain)

The difference between Sahih Al-Bukhari and Sahih Al-Muslim; since Muslim is student of Bukhari, is approx. 100 hadith.

If we combine hadith just from Sahih Al-Bukhari and Sahih Al-Muslim, we get approx. 4100 hadith.

And I have not read otherwise yet, but you can research on http://www.sunnah.com/ yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 27,649 without repetition according to Dr. Hamzah Ahmad Az-Zayn (the Director for the Center of Qur'an and Sunnah in Makkah) in his Mawsu'ah Al-Hadith As-Sahihah. Although its quite possible that there are more as he only counted what Al-Albani authenticated. This includes Athar of Sahabah and Tabi'in and what is Hasan.

Comment: All scholars agree that they are only around 4300 hadith so this depends on the interpretation. Whether one counts hassan hadith as a category of sahih.

Answer (score 0):

I agree there are almost 4600 Hades without repeating  in other
Wallah hu aalam

Comment: Please [back up](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/610/17163) claims by providing evidence.