# Musnad Ahmad Hadith Collection in English

Tags: hadith

Is there a sunnah.com-like web site where we can search (in English) hadith collection of Imam Ahmad? (Or, for that matter, any document in English in searchable form.)

Comment: I think in best case you would find some translation of a volume or so ...

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find such a site but in [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/EnglishTranslationOfMusnadImamAhmedBinHanbalVolume1) you will find 3 volumes of the hadith collections which is around 1/10 of the whole (4376 ahadith). Also read [Is Musnad Ahmed a book of Sahih Ahaadith?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25875/is-musnad-ahmed-a-book-of-sahih-ahaadith)

The translation is made by Nasiruddin al-Khattab and edited by Huda al-Khattab the collection was edited, researched and referenced by Darussalam 2012.

**Volume 1** covers:

- Musnad Abu Bakr Siddeq.
- Musnad 'Umar bin al-Khattab
- The hadeeth of as_Saqeefah
- Musnad 'Uthman bin 'Affan
- Musnad Ali ibn Abi Talib

**Volume 2** covers:

- completes the Musnads of the ten sahaba whom were promised paradise.
- ...
- starts the Musnad of ahl-alBayt

**Volume 3** covers:

- Musnad 'Abdullah bin al-'Abbas
- Musnad Abdullah bin Mas'ood

As the site only presents scanned copies of the volumes it is hard to search and use it in the way you may use sunnah.com

I have also found a part covering the Musnad of 'Aisha of ~2500 ahadith -unknown translator-