# Which are the Sahih hadith books?

Tags: hadith, sahih-bukhari, sahih-muslim

Some of them are saying that Sahih Al-Buhari and Sahih Muslim are the only sahih hadih books. Than what about the books like Thirmidhi and Abu-Dawud etc.

Comment: Which hadith is sahih is a matter of opinion we have a couple of books which are called sahih in their titles like "sahih" ibn Hebban, Muslim, al-Bukhari, ibn Khozaimah etc. but all these scholars have different interpretations of what is a sahih! I think I covered your issue in https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25875/is-musnad-ahmed-a-book-of-sahih-ahaadith/35443#35443, see also https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7718/how-many-sahihauthentic-hadith-are-there and https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/is-sahih-al-bukhari-considered-as-100-authentic-by-sunni-scholars

Answer (score 1):

**Kutub al-Sittah** or sometimes referred to as **Al-Sihah al-Sittah** are the six books of Hadith which are considered to be an authentic authority and contains Sahih Hadith of Prophet Muhammad (PBUH). The list of books with their authors is as follow.

- Sahih Bukhari, collected by Imam Bukhari (d. 256 AH, 870 CE), includes 7,275 ahadith
- Sahih Muslim, collected by Muslim b. al-Hajjaj (d. 261 AH, 875 CE), includes 9,200 ahadith
- Sunan Abu Dawood, collected by Abu Dawood (d. 275 AH, 888 CE), includes 4,800 ahadith
- Jami al-Tirmidhi, collected by al-Tirmidhi (d. 279 AH, 892 CE), includes 3,956 ahadith
- Sunan ibn Majah, collected by Ibn Majah (d. 273 AH, 887 CE), over 4,000 ahadith

Either

- Sunan al-Sughra, collected by al-Nasa'i (d. 303 AH, 915 CE), includes 5,270 ahadith
- Muwatta Malik, collected by Imam Malik (d. 179 AH, 795 CE), 1,720 ahadith

Comment: Muwatta' Malik doesn't include much more than 750 ahadith (prophetic traditions) -even in the biggest narrated version- from which al-Bukhari and Muslim have compiled more than 500. Most of the narrations in the book are fatwas and sayings of the sahaba.

Comment: Beside both al-Muwatta' and sunan abi Dawod primarly include ahadith of ahkam (fiqh rulings). While all others have a bigger variety of content.

Comment: But bottom line they provide Sahih ahadith as it was asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

The book which contain all Authentic Hadith is 'Jami ul Kamil' compiled by Imam Zia ur Rehman Azimi. It contains 16546 hadiths and printed in 12 volumes in Arabic Language. Its English translation is being under progress under supervision of Dr. Zakir Naik (95% completed), and its urdu translation is under progress under supervision of Maulana M. Ibrahim ibn Bashir and Ustad Abdul Rahman Mahdi (almost 50% completed). Its software construction is under progress under supervision of Ustad Abdul Rahman Mahdi.